# All4coding module doesn't work correct on magento

Tags: magento, helper

Sometimes my website stops working correctly, because it can't load `all4coging` module helper.
This is the error message from log -

```
Class 'Mage_All4coding_Core_Helper_Data' not found in /htdocs/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

But after deleting cache all works fine.  Please help with this issue.

Comment: Please add additional details, software, hardware etc. Can you post any code which might help people to find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Olegrav,Some where in your codes,you have called this code 
Mage::helper("all4coding);
Or helper class is  not declared properly in config.xml

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <yourhelpersname>
            <class>YourModulenameSpace_YurmoduleName_Helper</class>
        </yourhelpersname>
    </helpers   
</global>
```

Comment: It isn't my module, it is downloaded module and after installation all works good. I don't call it, system calls it dynamically. This module is encoded and I can't see code, there are only strange symbols in files. It is strange because all works good, but sometimes system can't find class from module and functionality begin to work bad(shows empty pages or part of page). After cleaning cache site begins to work good. Here is link to module I am using: http://all4coding.com/magento/google-adsense.html